# Why is j/with-connection an unknown var?

Tags: jdbc, clojure

I am using the SpringSource Informix JDBC driver for Clojure. I am getting an error when loading a file using `lein repl (load-file ...)` Here is the error:

`No such var: j/with-connection`

What am I doing wrong?

This function returns a database map to be used with a query (along with core.clj header)

```
(ns ics-db.core
  (require [clojure.string :as str])
  (require [clojure.java.jdbc :as j])
  (require [util.core :as utl])
  (:use [clojure.tools.cli])
  (:use [clojure.java.shell :only [sh]])
  (:import java.util.Date)
)

(def dbg 2)

(def if_SE_engine_type "SE")

(defn retn-informix-setup
"Sets up and returns a map structure that can be used elsewhere to talk to informix/ics"
[opts]
(let [start-time  (str (Date.))
  informix-db {:classname "com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver"
               :subprotocol "informix-sqli"
               :subname (format "//%s:%s/%s:informixserver=%s;usev5server=1;DBPATH=%s" 
               (:host opts)
               (:port opts)
               (:database opts)
               (:server opts)
               (:dbpath opts))
              }]
  informix-db))
```

This function takes the db map created above, and the select query works fine.

```
(defn ret-sel-query
  "Performs a selection query."
  [db-info query]
  (let [result (j/query db-info
                     [query])]
    result))
```

This is the function containing the `j/with-connection` that fails. This function tries to delete the row just queried:

```
(defn del-query
  "Performs a delete query."
  [db-info id]
  (let [result (j/with-connection db-info
                (j/delete-rows :real_estate [:acct_no id]))]))
```

This test function tests the select and delete. If I remove the code that attempts the delete, the selected row is selected, returned, and the println prints the row.

```
(if (>= (utl/chk-flagM dbg) 2)
  (do
      (defn test-1
        []
        (let [opts {:host "steamboy", 
                    :server "steamboy",
                    :database "ics",
                    :port 1498,
                    :dbpath "/home/ics/icsdev/"}

              informix-db (retn-informix-setup opts)

              sel-q "select r.* from real_estate r where r.acct_no = 70782"

              q-result (ret-sel-query informix-db sel-q)

              _  (del-query informix-db 70782)]



          (println q-result)))))
```

This modified function works, but I am wondering why the `with-connection` does not.

```
(defn del-query
  "Performs a delete query."
  [db-info id]
  (j/delete! db-info :real_estate ["acct_no = ?" id]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clojure.java.jdbc 0.3.x deprecated those functions. They are now accessible via the namespace [`clojure.java.jdbc.deprecated`](http://clojure.github.io/java.jdbc/#clojure.java.jdbc.deprecated). So either use that namespace, transform your code to use the new API or go back to an older version of the library.

Comment: I'll have to go update the wiki containing those examples. I also found this http://clojure.github.io/java.jdbc/ to be quite helpful, too.